# process.env sinon.stub value gives TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, stubbing

**sinon: ^7.5.0**
**mocha: 3.4.2**

Code is as follows based on this [documentation](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/)

> stub.value(newVal)
>   Defines a new value for this stub.
>   sinon.stub(myObj, 'example').value('newValue');

My code using **mocha** and **sinion**. I just want to stub the value for **process.env.NODE_ENV**.

```
sinon.stub(process.env, 'NODE_ENV').value("prod");
```

I have printed **proccess.env** and it has a **key** **NODE_ENV** that points to a String, `'dev'`.

Here's the outcome when running mocha's test.

```
TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string
  at module.exports (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/util/core/is-es-module.js:16:58)
  at stub (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/stub.js:28:9)
  at Sandbox.stub (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/sandbox.js:318:33)
```

The baffling thing is that this works:

```
let whatever= { another_key: { onemore: "pure"} };
sinon.stub(whatever.another_key, 'onemore').value("mashed");
```

I have also tried with sandbox (which I don't see why since as of v5 sinon is synonym for sandbox), for the heck of it.

```
let sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
describe(....
     ...
     beforeEach(function(){
         sandbox.stub(process.env, 'NODE_ENV').value('prod');
     });

      afterEach(function(){
        sandbox.restore();
      });
);
```

Same error.

Where have I gone wrong?

ps: I am aware I can save `process.env.NODE_ENV`, change it during testing, and set it back. That's my fallback plan.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for making a stub for `process.env.NODE_ENV`, before making the stub, we need declare the `NODE_ENV` property on `process.env` object. Otherwise, it will throw an error:

> TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property NODE_ENV

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import sinon from "sinon";
import { expect } from "chai";

describe("59214393", () => {
  it("should mock process.env", () => {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = "";
    const stub = sinon.stub(process.env, "NODE_ENV").value("prod");
    expect(process.env.NODE_ENV).to.be.eq("prod");
    stub.restore();
  });

  it("should back to original value", () => {
    expect(process.env.NODE_ENV).to.be.eq("");
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
  59214393
    ✓ should mock process.env
    ✓ should back to original value


  2 passing (11ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.test.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59214393

Comment: It gives me the following error: `ReferenceError: process is not defined`